# Обработка заштрихованной области в матрице

Tags: java, c++, матрицы

[image: Изображение заштрихованной области]

Всем привет, какое условие написать, чтобы обработать элементы находящиеся в заштрихованной области? Надо будет найти сумму отрицательных элементов.

Я так понимаю что в элементам квадратной матрицы, лежащим ниже побочной диагонали соответствует выражение i + j + 1 > n. Но как еще написать чтоб оно не брало квадратик этот? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: А каким значениям соответствуют верхняя горизонталь и левая вертикаль квадрата?

Comment: @MBo, всмысле? ну допустим матрица 10x10

Comment: Ага, и какой строчке соответствует верхняя сторона квадрата в таком случае?

Comment: @MBo, нулевой??

Comment: Маленького квадратика

Comment: @MBo, будет N / 2 ?

Comment: Точно, и с вертикалью так же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((i + j + 1 > n) && ((i < n/2) || (j < n/2)))
```

Comment: Работает) спасибо

Comment: А отработает ли если N будет нечетным?

Comment: Тут по рисунку точно не скажешь, что они имели в виду. Можно `(n+1)/2` использовать, при целочисленном делении это и для чётного сгодится. При размере 7 тогда будут использоваться строки 0,1,2,3